# PSP 2000 has a solid orange power light and is a struggle to turn on or off

Tags: technical-issues, psp

I was wondering about the problem of my PSP 2000, I can't turn it on properly like I have to try many times just to power it on from sleep mode, same as making it go to sleep mode. Plus the Power Light is solid Orange. I tried googling the problem but most of it were not helping. Could there be a problem with the power board?

PS: Sorry for the dirty hands, I was fixing printers in the office earlier

[Here's the video of the problem](https://youtu.be/oSrGZC6tqHg)

Answer (score 0):

The power switch connector is either dirty or failing. I have a 3000 with the same problem so I feel your pain. Ultimately you're going to either need to locate a repair shop with experience working on PSPs to examine the system and if needed replace the power switch, or pick up a used replacement system and migrate you data to it.

If you're feeling brave there are online tutorials on how to disasemble the system and clean it, so that's a cheep first step you can try.

If that doesn't work then you can always try do the repair yourself if you're skilled with working with electronics in that way. I'm sure you may be able either find a replacement switch online or find another 2000 with maybe a broken screen to swap the switch from.

As for the orange, I'm just going to suspect that's a battery related issue.

Good luck!